# Conditional shortcode based on product price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, price

Im trying to make a wordpress shortcode that print "Free Shipping" if product price is greater than 8$, if not returns blank (prints nothing).

```
function shortcode_FreeShipping( $product ) {
  if( $product->get_price() > 8 ) {
     return __( 'Free Shipping', 'woocommerce' );
  }
  else {
     return __( '', 'woocommerce' );
  }
}
add_shortcode('freeshipping', 'shortcode_FreeShipping');
```

When shortcode `[freeshipping]` in inserted on product page, the page doesn't load.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead where `$product` (the `WC_Product` object instance) is correctly called:

```
function shortcode_freeshipping( $atts ) {
    // Only on single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return;

    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'price' => 8 // HERE you set your default price
    ), $atts, 'freeshipping' );

    global $product;

    if( ! is_object($product) )
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

    if( $product->get_price() > $atts['price'] ) {
        return __( 'Free Shipping', 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
        return __( '', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
add_shortcode('freeshipping', 'shortcode_freeshipping');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE - 2 possibilities:**

1) With the default defined price:

```
[freeshipping]
```

2) With a custom price (using the **`price`** argument):

```
[freeshipping price="10"]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. The custom price argument is very useful too :)

Comment: Is this also possible with Woocommerce calling the free shipping rules from settings? Instead of enter the value yourself? So when I change the free shipping rules in setting it also changes here?